# What is the difference between an active window and a focused window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I keep seeing all these references in the documentation to the active window and also to the focused window. I cannot find definitions for these terms or any explanation of the difference between them. Does anyone else have a better understanding of this?